# git pushing one local commit to github is ignored ("Everything up-to-date")

Tags: git, github

first remote: "alioth" https://anonscm.debian.org/git/collab-maint/wicd.git

second remote: "github" https://github.com/toogley/pkg-wicd

I have fetched the last commit from alioth, but when i want to "git push --all github" that one, my git says "Everything up-to-date", although my remote branch differs in my opinion to my local one, in exactly that `77479e9` commit.

I have currently those (local) git logs:

```
* 77479e9 (tag: debian/1.7.3-1, alioth/master) Upload to unstable as 1.7.3-1
* ffc4dce closing #582567, which was fixed upstream in 1.7.3
* 31bd86d Add patch to show "Q" as key to quit the wireless network property view
* 88e8121 Add patch to fix "ValueError: None is not in list" in wicd-curses
| * b2931ca (HEAD, github/master, github/HEAD, master) closing #582567, which was fixed upstream in 1.7.2.4
```

==> What is wrong here?

**EDIT** To clarify: i have the permissions to do what i want. I have successfully fetched from the debian repo and want to push to **my** github repo. So, of course i have the permissions.

Comment: What branch are you on locally?

Comment: @deborah-digges master. @ msw: i clarified that in my post. i have the permissions.

Comment: The distinction between fetch and pull comes into play here... a pull does a merge which hasn't happened yet

Comment: @JoePhilllips yeah, i've just missed that... sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is *wrong*, in the sense that git is behaving as intended.

When you use `git push --all` you are essentially supplying the refspec `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`.  That is, take all your local branches and ask the remote to set its branches to the same commits.

So, using the above, let's see what local branches you have:

```
* 77479e9 (tag: debian/1.7.3-1, alioth/master) ...
```

This has one tag (not a branch) and one remote-tracking branch (not a local branch).

```
* ffc4dce ...
```

This has no outside references at all (found via parent link instead).

```
* 31bd86d ...
* 88e8121 ...
```

Likewise for these two.

```
| * b2931ca (HEAD, github/master, github/HEAD, master) ...
```

This has *four* references: `HEAD` (i.e., is your current branch), `github/master` (a remote-tracking branch), `github/HEAD` (remote-tracking again), and `master`.

Aha!  There is one local branch, named `master`, which identifies commit `b2931ca`.  So you connect to github to ask their git to set one branch named `master` to `b2931ca`, and, well, it's already there, nothing to do.

If you wish to add some commits to your local `master` before pushing—and no doubt you do—you must do that.  Probably you want to `git merge` them, perhaps as a fast-forward operation, perhaps as a forced merge (this is a matter of taste and strategy, not a technical issue):

```
git merge --ff-only alioth/master
```

or:

```
git merge --no-ff alioth/master
```

(or with no flag, let git decide).

Comment: Hey, thanks, works perfectly. i just missed/forgot that i had to merge that in my master..